# Definir key do objeto por uma variavel

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte objeto

```
Perfil1 ["Souza", "4", "3"]
Perfil2 ["Pedro", "2", "1"]
Perfil3 ["Lucas", "5", "8"]
```

e um for que vai de 1 ao 10

como eu faço para mudar o numero do perfil de cada key de acordo com o number do for

Tentei fazer assim, porem sem sucesso

```
//Number é o numero que o for gera
console.log(perfil.Perfil+Number);
```

Exemplo:

```js
var obj = [{  
   "Perfil1":[  
      "Pedro",
      "5",
      "1"
   ],
   "Perfil2":[  
      "Marcos",
      "2",
      "2"
   ],
   "Perfil3":[  
      "Joao",
      "2",
      "1"
   ]
}]

var numero = new Number();

var numero = 2;//Quero definir um numero aqui, por exemplo 2 para "Marcos"


console.log(obj[0].Perfil + numero);//Retorna NaN

console.log(obj[0].Perfil2);//Setando direto ele retorna o resultado
```

Comment: O que seria "número de perfil"? Tem como fazer um [mcve]?

Comment: um momento vou fazer

Comment: Isso ja não resolveria a questão no NaN: 
console.log(obj[0].Perfil + ''+ numero) ?

Comment: Seria mais semântico usar array de objetos ao invés de array de objetos de array. Precisa mesmo seguir nesse formato?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os objectos no JavaScript se comportam como dicionarios de chave-valor, então é possível acessa-los pelo nome.

```
console.log(obj[0]["Perfil" + numero]);
```

se a ideia é modificar o numero do perfil, pode fazer da seguinte forma.:

```js
var obj = [{  
   "Perfil1":[ "Pedro", "5", "1" ],
   "Perfil2":[ "Marcos", "2", "2" ],
   "Perfil3":[ "Joao", "2", "1" ]
}]

var perfis = obj[0];
var trocarNumero = function (ori, dst) {
  if (perfis["Perfil" + ori] && !perfis["Perfil" + dst]) {
    var perfil = perfis["Perfil" + ori];
    perfis["Perfil" + dst] = perfil;
    delete perfis["Perfil" + ori];
  }
};

trocarNumero(1, 5);
console.log(perfis);
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON forma uma estrutura de dados poderosa da qual você pode se aproveitar melhor. Minha sugestão é você alterar para um *array* de objetos para representar o cenário.

Ao invés de:

```
[
   {
    A: [idx1, idx2],
    B: [idx1, idx2]
   }
]
```

Poderia ser:

```
[{
    "nome": "A",
    "idade": "X",
    "numero": "Y"
}, {
    "nome": "B",
    "idade": "X",
    "numero": "Y"
}]
```

**Exemplo**

```js
var perfis = [{
    nome: "Pedro",
    idade: 20,
    numero: 10
  },
  {
    nome: "Marcos",
    idade: 30,
    numero: 20
  }
];
perfis[1].numero = 1; // altera o numero do perfil do Marcos
console.log(perfis[1]);
```